# Is it possible to use a sectionKeyPath with NSFetchedResultsController when fetching properties with NSDictionaryResultType?

Tags: ios, core-data, mobile, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I've got a fetch request set up to retrieve some properties on 'User' items:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:companyName, firstName, lastName, completeItems, incompleteItems, objectID, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:SortOptionCompany ascending:YES],
                                   [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:SortOptionFirstName ascending:YES]]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:kBatchSize];
```

I initialize my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                      managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                                        sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                                                                                 cacheName:nil];
```

The attribute "sectionIdentifier" is a transient property on the User entity. However, when I execute this, I get the message:

```
"returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Object will be placed in unnamed section"
```

The fetched information isn't grouped into sections as desired. Is this because I need to fetch whole NSManagedObjects for the keyPath to not be nil, or is there a way to use sectionKeyPath when retrieving dictionaries? I've also tried using setPropertiesToGroupBy: with no success.

Comment: Have you tried including sectionIdentifier in the array of properties to fetch?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, it doesn't work, I'm guessing because sectionIdentifier is a transient property. I've tried using a non-transient property that is both in propertiesToFetch: and sectionKeyPath: and that results in the same message as shown in the question.

Comment: After a bit of testing, I have been able to get sectionNameKeyPath to work, but only for a non-transient property.  So it's possible.  But if I use a property which has nil values, I get the same message.

Comment: @pbasdf How can I ensure the property doesn't have nil values? The non-transient property I was trying to use for sectionKeyPath wasn't nil when I was displaying it in the UITableViewCell text.

Comment: Did you include it in your `propertiesToFetch`?

Comment: @pbasdf Yeah I included it in propertiesToFetch and still get the same message. It works properly without the NSDictionaryResultType, but not when that result type is set on the fetch request.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with NSDictionaryResultType (any reason you are sticking to that?).  One difficulty is that your sort descriptors must order things correctly, but cannot use transient properties.

Comment: @pbasdf Ah, alright. The sort descriptors are ordering the data exactly as I want it, it's just not being sectioned in the table view. I wanted to use NSDictionaryResultType as I'm fetching certain counts for attributes on nested relationships using NSExpression. I think this would be more expensive to do with fetching whole objects and then calculating the information that can be accessed using propertiesToFetch.

Comment: Ah yes, I see why NSDictionary is necessary then.  Sorry, I can't see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no solution that I could find for this issue, I resorted to not using a sectionKeyPath and sorting the data into sections manually after retrieval.